# Inserting a node in Binary Tree

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, queue

I am trying to insert 1 to 7 numbers in Binary tree. And after that using Level-order-Traversal to traverse the tree.
Here is the function I am using to insert into the node:

```
void InsertIntoBinaryTree(struct BinaryTree **root,int data)
{
    struct BinaryTree *newNode,*tempNode;
    struct Queue queue;

    newNode = (struct BinaryTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTree));
    newNode -> data = data;
    newNode -> left = newNode -> right = NULL; 
    if(!*root)
    {
        *root = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        queue.rear = -1;
        Enqueue(&queue,*root);
        while(queue.front != -1)
        {
            tempNode = Dequeue(&queue);
            if(tempNode -> left)
            {
                Enqueue(&queue,tempNode -> left);
            }
            else
            {
                tempNode -> left = newNode;
                return;
            }
            if(tempNode -> right)
            {
                Enqueue(&queue,tempNode -> right);
            }
            else
            {
                tempNode -> right = newNode;
                return;
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

`root` node is being inserted successfully but others nodes not.
After the insertion of `root` node , I am assigning new node to left of the `root` node and after that to right of the `root`. The new nodes are assigned but once I traverse the tree the child nodes are not showing and the child nodes are not being enqueued to temporary queue that I am using to keep track of parsed nodes. 
Here is the function using for level order traversal:

```
void LevelOrderTraversal(struct BinaryTree *root)
{
    struct Queue q;
    struct BinaryTree *tempNode;
    if(root)
    {
        q.rear = -1;
        Enqueue(&q,root);
        while(q.front != -1)
        {
            tempNode = Dequeue(&q);
            printf("address:%u and data:%d\t",tempNode,tempNode -> data);
            if(tempNode -> left)
                Enqueue(&q,tempNode -> left);
            if(tempNode -> right)
                Enqueue(&q,tempNode -> right);
        }   
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Please help to figure out where I am going wrong.
**Edit**: Here is code for Enqueue and Dequeue:

```
void Enqueue(struct Queue *q,struct BinaryTree *root)
{
    // check queue is full.................
       if((q -> rear + 1)% MAX==q->front)
       printf("queue is full");
       else{

        if((q -> rear == -1)||(q->front==-1))
        q -> rear = q -> front = 0;
          else
        q -> rear = (q -> rear + 1)% MAX;
        q -> a[q -> rear] = root;
         }
      }
struct BinaryTree *Dequeue(struct Queue *q)
{
    struct BinaryTree *temp;
    if(q->front==-1)
        return NULL;
    else{
        temp = q -> a[q -> front];
        if(q -> front == q -> rear)
        q -> front = q -> front = -1;
        else
        q -> front = (q -> front + 1)% MAX;
          return temp;
     }
}
```

Comment: The shown code inserts and traverses the tree level-wise (breadth first). Does the queue work as intended?

Comment: Yes, queue is working well.

Comment: Your queue works, basically. In `Dequeue`, you probably want `q->front = q->rear = -1;`. There may be cases where you initialise `q.rear = -1` and the uninitialised `q.front` is 0, which leads the queue to think it is full, although it isn't. Further, you should either print the value of a pointer with `%p` or cast it to `(unsigned int)` when printing it. Another pitfall that I can think of is that you don't initialise your root to `NULL`. Other than that, your code should work.

Comment: yes. thanks I got it. I was missing `q.front = -1` in `main`  method.